# "To get something done" versus "to have something done"?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between these two words in the following examples:

1. Why don't you **get** your hair cut?
2. Why don't you **have** your hair cut?

Comment: Technically, that's an unanswered question, since there are no votes oforn either answer. This is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a haircut there's no difference. But, e.g., "get the roof fixed" *might* mean you're going to fix it yourself, while "have the roof fixed" definitely means  'fixed by someone else'.

Comment: I think "definitely" is too strong. Consider "You better have the roof fixed when I get back!".

Comment: Fair comment, Yossarian! I withdraw the 'definitely'.

Comment: @Yossarian.  I realized later that there's a link between this question and one I posed on the Linguistics site [How did the same perfect-tense structure become so widespread in Europe?]  "You better have the roof fixed" = "You better see that the roof becomes fixed [by whomever]".  While "You better have fixed the roof" is a perfect-tense construction.